# Bulk_create is not working with batch_size parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to use bulk_create, but it is only creating one object instead of the batch_size I stipulated. I'm using a variable for batch_size, so maybe that's the issue, but I can't think of why it should be a problem. Here's the code:

```
            x = 40 / 2
            if 5 > 4:
                objs1 = 
                 ModelT(
                        name=instance.name,
                        author=instance.author,
                        content=instance.content
                    )

                ModelT.objects.bulk_create(objs1, batch_size=x)
```

I've also tried it with:

```
                    ModelT.objects.bulk_create(objs1, x)
```

and did not work either.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour: you here passed a list to the function with *one* object.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work". If there's an error, include the traceback. If there's no error, explain what the expected result was, and what the actual result was.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What about now?

Comment: @HåkenLid No error, as I said, it's only creating one object when I expected it to create as many as the batch size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) stores a *list* of objects into the database. The `batch_size` is used to determine how many objects are stored in the database *per query*.

For example if you have a list of 100 elements, and the `batch_size=10`, it will result in 10 queries, if `batch_size=25`, it will result in 4 queries (given the queries are not too long). Or as specified in the documentation:

> This method inserts the **provided list of objects** into the database
> in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
> objects there are).

The `batch_size` parameter is thus only used to "throttle" the number of elements you store per query, for some database systems, it might be better to use several queries, such that the table is for example still accessible during a huge insert.

Here you however only have given the function a list of *one* elements, so regardless of the `batch_size`, you can however create a list of 20 `ModelT`s:

```
objs1 = [
    ModelT(name=instance.name, author=instance.author, content=instance.content)
    for _ in range(20)
]

ModelT.objects.bulk_create(objs1)
```

If all objects have the same content, we can even multiply with a number:

```
objs1 = [
    ModelT(name=instance.name, author=instance.author, content=instance.content)
] * 20

ModelT.objects.bulk_create(objs1)
```

Note that, as said in the documentation, no `pre_save` and `post_save` signals will fire, and unless the database backend is PostgreSQL, the `id` of the object is *not* set (for the latter appraoch, this will not work, since here we constructed a list with 20 references to the *same* object).

You can here still specify a `batch_size`, with the semantics described above, but this will not make a *functional* difference.

Comment: Great, thanks for that explanation. Now it's working as intended. Also, do you have any input on ideal batch_size for performance, and anything I should look out for when bulk_creating large numbers of objects? If need be I'll put this in another question. In any case thanks for your help.

Comment: @Whodini: if you do not specify a batch size, it will construct all objects with a *single* query, which is normally the fastest way to insert data. The problem that might occur is that if the inseration takes a long time, at that moment - depending on how the database works - the table might be unaccessible by other threads. But if the objects are relatively small (<100), normally there is no problem, and the `batch_size` can be omitted.

Comment: Since the number of objects created dependent on that variable, I anticipate the variable will be lower numbers in the beginning, but over time it may increase into the thousands, or millions, or who knows. Ideally I'd like to set a manageable number from the get go that will both get the job done and prevent timeouts or other problems. Btw I'm using Postgres.

Comment: Right now I have it set at 100.

Comment: @Whodini: then you can perhaps set it to `batch_size=100`. EDIT: we came up with the same value :)

Comment: In case later it turns out that this "bulk create" disrupts the service, you can set it lower, but typically 100 will not be that problematic I think.

Comment: Ok, will keep it at that for now. Thanks, Willem.